# Rounded UIButton corner leads to weird appearance

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I am generating my custom view controller's view programmatically, including adding a few buttons. I have three buttons in a row, all created along the lines of this one:

```
self.futureButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, buttonOffset, _width/3, _height*.1)];
self.futureButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor pinkColor];
self.futureButton.tag = 1;
[self.futureButton setTitle:@"Upcoming" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.futureButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self setColor:[UIColor lightPinkColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected forButton:self.futureButton];
[self.futureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changAppt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.futureButton];
```

I also do this at the end to apply the same properties to all these buttons:

```
 for(UIButton *myButton in self.view.subviews){
             if([myButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                 [[myButton layer] setBorderWidth:4.0f];
                 [[myButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
                 [myButton.layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];<----problem
             }
 }
```

Everything is working great except the last command, setCornerRadius. If I comment it out, I have what I want - all the buttons lined up, white border that disappears into the background white. However if I use this last command, setCornerRadius, I get the following (see image)

[image: weird corners]

Also the weird effect is on whichever button is selected. Do I have to do something about the selected state effects and the CornerRadius? If so, what?

Comment: have my answer fixed the problem? looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add

```
myButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

and this is it :)

If you are interested in more details [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds).